# Is there any way to Delete and update Facebook product catalog product with Facebook Graph API

Tags: curl, facebook-graph-api, postman, facebook-business-sdk, facebook-business-manager

I am trying to to Update and Delete product to facebook product catalog with graph api.

I followed this [documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/product-catalog/products/) but this endpoint only allow read and create new product to a product catalog but update and delete is not possible from this endpoint. Is it possible to do??

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/product-item/#Updating

Answer (score 0):

The documentation here is a bit confusing. There is an older endpoint for [/batch](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/product-item/#overview). This is a legacy endpoint, but the documentation here might help you craft a payload for the new endpoint.

The [items_batch endpoint](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/catalog-batch/) should be the most up-to-date endpoint for these operations.

The autogenerated documentation claims that it doesn't support update or delete, however it should actually support CREATE, UPDATE, and DELETE.

I believe that you pass it a JSON object containing multiple [product items](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/product-catalog/items_batch/) and the CRUD verb.